# Does the std::string copy constructor add null character at the end by itself?

Tags: c++, function, stl, iostream

First I was doing,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo (std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    char st[] = "0";
    st[1] = '[';
    std::string s (st);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It shows junk when I send to the stream object `cout` using stream insertion operator (guess it is a normal behaviour).

Then I checked by passing to a function `foo` by value.
I'm doing something like this now.

```
    foo (s);

    // after calling foo () value printed by the
    // std::cout is changed. it takes care of NULL character ('\0')
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

It doesn't show junk after `0[` anymore. Why?

My question is,
I passed the string in `foo ()` by value. There run a copy constructor before the body of the `foo ()` is run. But still doesn't make sense. How can this `copyctor` change parameter passed from `main ()` by value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Undefined Behavior because you broke your string.

Comment: Open your program in a debugger, and see what `st` points at. Then you'll know.

Comment: I was in the process of answering your question about ISRs when you deleted it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char st[] = "0";
```

Pop Quiz:  How big is `st`?

Answer:  Two `chars`  One for the `"0`", and one for the null-terminator.

Then you go and overwrite the null terminator:

```
st[1] = '[';
```

...and try to construct a `string` based on that:

```
std::string s (st);
```

The `string` constructor which takes a `const char*` is being invoked here, and the way it works is it looks for the null-terminator.  Since you blew it away, it's going to run past the end of `st`.  Running past the end of `st` evokes Undefined Behavior, and is the reason why you see garbage.

It's important to note that Undefined Behavior means **anything** can happen.  "Anything" here includes "exactly what I want to happen". It doesn't necessarily that you'll get garbage output, or that your program will crash.  Trying to reason out why UB manifests itself in this way or that is an unreasonable effort.

Comment: And important to note: undefined behavior need not be consistent.

Comment: Then why doesn't show junk when I pass to foo ()? cout prints till null. Right?

Comment: @Fahad: Maybe the first piece of junk happens to be a `'\0'`. You're trying to rationalise about the unrationalisable.

Comment: @Fahad:  Undefined Behavior means *anything can happen* -- which includes exactly what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Fahad: You invoked undefined behavior. As R Sahu said in another answer, "Anything could happen after that." The program might read your mind do just what you want. Or it might erase your hard drive.

Comment: UB is over-invoked on SO, though. This OP _wants_ a practical explanation, and one can be provided, trivially. Whittering on about the undefined nature of this program at the abstract level is not useful. For example, this program will _never_ actually erase your hard drive, and it will _never_ make your nose run. Ever. This is because the question is about how a program behaves when it is executed on an actual computer that exists in our physical reality.

Comment: No, I'm sure it can't erase hard drive. I'm causing a read operation not a write one.
Well, why does function passing changes the value inside main ()?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  In that case, the only reasonable answer is to step in to the debugger and see what the `string` constructor actually does, and what memory actually looks like.

Comment: @JohnDibling: We can make a reasonable assumption based on how computers work, as long as we attach a disclaimer that it's only a guess. With C-strings, though, there is not a lot to debate.

Answer (score 3):

People are telling you about undefined behaviour. That's great, but you already know that.

In practice, the key here is that your first "junk" character may well be a `'\0'` character itself, in which case you won't see any bytes further than that.

You can't just assume that you're going to see at least 20 arbitrary characters, because one completely plausible outcome of your code is that you see 0 arbitrary characters.

In short, you're attempting to rationalise the unrationalisable; stop it!

Comment: Is that really a word?

Comment: @JohnDibling: It is now

Answer (score 1):

After these two lines:

```
char st[] = "0";
st[1] = '[';
```

`st` is not a null terminated string. `std::string(char const*)` expects a null terminated string. Since the input to the constructor of `std:string` does not meet that criterion, you are entering undefined behavior territory. Anything could happen after that.

Comment: I did it on purpose. Why doesn't show junk when passed to the after passing to function foo ()? Question is: why function foo changed the object passed from main ().

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
char st[] = "0";
```

causes the compiler to allocate a 2 byte array fixed-size array and fill it with "0\0" (ASCII 0 followed by a null character). This line

```
st[1] = '[';
```

then assigns '[' to the location previously occupied by the NULL, destroying the null-termination of your string. Then this line

```
std::string s (st);
```

will start at the beginning of `st` and keep copying chars into `s` until it finds a null somewhere in memory. That's why you're seeing garbage.